# How generate controller (admin) in separate folder with console

Tags: cakephp, console, cakephp-3.x

I want to make an app which includes ,admin and client , how should I bake controller (admin) in separate folder with console.
i tried couple of console codes but in didn't work with i want!

I tried in console:

```
cake bake all admin
```

and it made:

```
cake/src/controller/Admin/AdminController.php
```

but I want to make some thing like that:

```
cake/src/controller/Adminstrator/Admin/DashbordController.php
```

what should I do?

Comment: bake Administrator plugin, then inside bake Admin prefixed controllers, models,..

Comment: i bake a adminstrator with console  and what should i do now  ?i dont know how to bake admin prefixed ... what is the exactly console code ?? help me plz...

Comment: Please specify CakePHP version

Answer (score 3):

**[Code Generation with Bake](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html)**

Create Administrator plugin:

```
cake bake plugin Administrator
```

Create Admin prefixed Dashboard inside Administrator plugin:

```
cake bake controller Dashboard -p Administrator --prefix Admin
```

Comment: @sadeqmolaee Accept answer